# Menu does not close when clicking outside of it on Mobile device

Tags: jquery, html

I made a menu that appears on a button click, and then closes upon clicking anywhere. It works perfectly fine on desktop, but it's not working on Mobile, can't seem to figure out why. Your help is very welcomed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="filter-menu-toggle">
    Sort <span class="menu-toggle-name">End Date</span><i class="icon-arrow_drop_down"></i>
</div>


<div id="campaign-sort-filter"> 

    <div class="filter-menu-dropdown menu-pos-2">
        <ul>
            <li class="filter-menu-item">
                <a href="#" class="filter-menu-link">End Date</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter-menu-item">
                <a href="#" class="filter-menu-link">Start Date</a>
            </li>   
        </ul>                   
    </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var menuwashandled=false;

jQuery('#campaign-sort-filter').on('click', function(){
if (jQuery('#campaign-sort-filter .filter-menu-dropdown').css('display') == 'none')
    jQuery('#campaign-sort-filter .filter-menu-dropdown').fadeIn(100);
else
    jQuery('#campaign-sort-filter .filter-menu-dropdown').fadeOut(100);
menuwashandled = '#campaign-sort-filter';
});

/* catch global click event and hide all menues expect for the one that was handled if such exists */

jQuery('html').click(function() {
  if (menuwashandled != '#campaign-sort-filter')
     jQuery('#campaign-sort-filter .filter-menu-dropdown').fadeOut(100);
  menuwashandled = false;
});
```

Is there a better way of doing this that is more mobile friendly? Or just better in general?

Comment: replace html with document ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq No difference. Thanks though.